# Change color of a pixel without using 'graphics.h' library in C

Tags: c, pointers, file-io

I need to learn this stuff in order to pass the exams  so 
I tried this code but it didn’t work. How can I get it to work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "img_header.h"
```

('img_header.h' contains some functions)

```
void simple_rgb_image_init(Simple_RGB_Image* sink, int32_t  width, int32_t  height);


typedef struct {
int32_t width;
int32_t height;
uint8_t* data;
} Simple_RGB_Image;


int main()
{

Simple_RGB_Image img;
int32_t width = 3;
int32_t height = 3;
FILE* out_file;

int32_t w;
int32_t x,y ;

uint8_t red,green,blue;

uint8_t* p_red;
uint8_t* p_green;
uint8_t* p_blue;

p_red   = &red;
p_green = &green;
p_blue  = &blue;

simple_rgb_image_init(&img,width,height);  

x = 1 ;
y = 1 ;
w = calculate_stride(width);   //calculate the stride

blue  = img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 0];
green = img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 1];
red   = img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 3];

printf("blue = %i \n" , blue);  //205
printf("green = %i \n" , green);//205
printf("red = %i \n" , red);    //205

printf("\n\n");

*p_red   = 0;
*p_green = 0;
*p_blue  = 255;

printf("blue = %i \n" , blue);  //255
printf("green = %i \n" , green);//0
printf("red = %i \n" , red);    //0


out_file = fopen("My_picture.bmp","wb");
simple_rgb_image_to_bitmap_stream(&img,out_file); //save the picture as a Bitmap file
fclose(out_file);
simple_rgb_image_clear(&img); //Free memory



return 0;
}


void simple_rgb_image_init(Simple_RGB_Image* sink, int32_t  width, int32_t  height)
{
sink->width = width;
sink->height = height;
sink->data = (uint8_t*)malloc(3 * width * height);
}
```

---

I did dealt directly with pointers , but in vain ! The code is still generating a 9 Pixels Bitmap-image ,with the color (Red = 205 , Blue = 205 , Green = 205) and that seems  a strange result cause when I compile the code , it prints out this:

```
blue = 0
green = 72
red = 45 

blue = 255
green = 0 
red = 0 

Press any key to continue . . .
```

and the code is :

```
p_blue  = &(img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 0]);
p_green = &(img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 1]);
p_red   = &(img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 2]);

printf("blue = %i \n" , *p_blue);  
printf("green = %i \n" , *p_green);
printf("red = %i \n" , *p_red);    

printf("\n\n");

*p_red   = 0;
*p_green = 0;
*p_blue  = 255;

printf("blue = %i \n" , *p_blue);  
printf("green = %i \n" , *p_green);
printf("red = %i \n" , *p_red);
```

Comment: Is it possible to improve your question ? What doesn't work? What did you try? What error did you get?

Comment: there is no errors , its just the result is not what I want ,
I tried those two methods : 
1) declaring local variables 
2) working directly with pointers and changing their values.
but I still cant change the color of pixel  P(1,1)

Comment: what result did you want and what result did you get?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, you're making changes to the local variable `red`, `green`, `blue`. The chages are not reflected inside `img`.

Instead, get rid of these local variables and directly deal with the pointers, like

```
p_blue  = &(img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 0]);
p_green = &(img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 1]);
p_red   = &(img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 3]);  //are you sure, this is 3. not 2?
```

and then, if you do

```
*p_red   = 0;
*p_green = 0;
*p_blue  = 255;
```

it will be reflected in `img`.

That said, please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: @K.F did you check actually `fopen()` was successful or not?

Comment: I did dealt directly with pointers , but in vain ! The code is still generating a 9 Pixels Bitmap-image ,with the color (Red = 205 , Blue = 205 , Green = 205) and that's seems a strange result cause when I compile the code , it prints out this: 
"

blue = 0
green = 72
red = 45


blue = 255
green = 0
red = 0

Press any key to continue . . .  "

Comment: and the code is :

        p_blue  = &(img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 0]);
 p_green = &(img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 1]);
 p_red   = &(img.data[3 *(w*y + x) + 2]);

 printf("blue = %i \n" , *p_blue);  
 printf("green = %i \n" , *p_green);
 printf("red = %i \n" , *p_red);    
 
 printf("\n\n");

 *p_red   = 0;
 *p_green = 0;
 *p_blue  = 255;

 printf("blue = %i \n" , *p_blue);  
 printf("green = %i \n" , *p_green);
    printf("red = %i \n" , *p_red);

Comment: @K.F code is not readable in comment. can you please use http://ideone.com/ to paste and show your code?

Comment: when I compile the code , it creates a picture with the name 'My_picture.bmp' in the specific folder ,
that means fopen() worked just fine , or ?